# google places api ignores rank by distance

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api, google-places

i have a problem with this request. The rankby Parameter seems to be ignored. i read many posts, but nothing could change my results.

Thank you for every help!

```
var request = {
                location: location,
                radius: 5000,
                types: ['bus_station','train_station'],
                rankby: 'distance',
                language: 'DE'
              };
```

`service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
 service.nearbySearch(request, callback);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 problems in your code.

1. Instead of *rankby* it should be *rankBy*
2. You are not allowed to use the *radius* attribute along with the *rankBy* attribute.

If your code doen't work after these steps then after the colon as the value of the rankBy attribute consider putting the following:

`rankBy: google.maps.places.RankBy.DISTANCE`

Othewise, extend your code.